# My Leaflet map is shown but looks like disabled

Tags: dictionary, leaflet, disable

I am starting using leaflet.js and I have a question about it, If someone could help , It would be great.

The problem is my map is displayed but can't do anything on it. It is like if it was disabled or somthing like that. You can find the code below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2OW8.png)

[check image to see what I meant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HazGA.png)

```
var map = new L.map('map').setView([43.1242, 5.9280], 13);
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors,' +
            '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>'}
    ).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Your code works on my machine. Perhaps test on a different browser? Your 'L.tilelayer..' doesn't need to be indented.

Comment: I just tested on several browers (firefix, I.E, Chrome) still the same result :-(, Don(t know what I should do

Comment: can you post the rest of your code so I can take a look? including imports. It works on my machine so there's nothing wrong with that code you've posted.

Comment: I cannot post all the code here because it depends on several files too, I wont be possible unfortunately !